# install ant in declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a Jenkins file for my ant application. I have already done the git checkout. Now I am want to install the ant plugin using the pipeline instead of manually.

I am getting the error :
script.sh: ant: not found

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        node{
            label 'pqr'
            }
    }
    
    stages{

        stage('Pull Source Code') {
            steps{
                
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: scm.branches,
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption', disableSubmodules: false, recursiveSubmodules: true, reference: '', trackingSubmodules: false]],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs])
                    echo "${scm.branches}"
            }


      }
      stage('Ant version') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Ant"
                sh 'ant -version'                     
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to install Ant every time you execute the pipeline? I would suggest using either a Docker container for that or install it on your agent with the label 'pqr'.

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell  I have got that installed at the plugin level..However, I am juggling with the build step requird for building the ant artifact...its says build.xml not found